# Issues with IIS 6.0 on fresh Server 2003 SP2 install

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003

Unfortunately I don't have a lot of technical information to give you but I will give as thorough a description as I can.

I have done a fresh install of Windows Server 2003 Enterprise (SP1). Performed all the updates including SP2 and installed McAfee Enterprise 8.7. Once I've completed doing this I open up the Windows Components installation and check "Application Server" which should install the base IIS installation.

The install runs fine and I reboot just for good measure. When I go into services I see IIS Admin started. Pulling up the IIS Manager reveals that the DefaultAppPool and the Default Web Site are both stopped. Attempting to start the Default Web Site results in no failure message and no entries in the Event Log. This doesn't surprise me terribly as it depends on the DefaultAppPool. When I try to start the DefaultAppPool after a few seconds I get an error "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion." and there is still no messages written to the event log.

I've tried this exact installation procedure twice now with identical results. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around if not a complete solution. I installed and configured IIS before updating or installing McAfee. IIS worked fine. Since I got it working I didn't want to go back and do a fresh installation but now that I think about it I might have just needed to run updates one more time after installing IIS. The order I installed it did allow me to get it to working so good luck to anyone else that has this issue. I hope this helps.